# CocoaPods file reference is a member of multiple groups

Tags: cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I have an app with a share extension. My app depends on `CocoaLumberjack/Default`, and my share extension depends on `CocoaLumberjack/Core`. When I build with `use_frameworks!`, I get the following error:

```
$ rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock; pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaLumberjack (2.0.3)
Generating Pods project
```

> 2015-10-28 10:46:04.015 ruby[53095:3440989] warning:  The file
>   reference for "CocoaLumberjack.framework" is a member of multiple
>   groups ("Products" and "Products"); this indicates a malformed
>   project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved
>   (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a
>   reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
>   reference to the same path.

```
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 1 total
pod installed.

[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:
```

> PBXFileReference --
>   /mainGroup/children/children:displayName:CocoaLumberjack.framework,explicitFileType:wrapper.framework,includeInIndex:0,isa:PBXFileReference,name:CocoaLumberjack.framework,path:CocoaLumberjack.framework,sourceTree:BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR,,displayName:CocoaLumberjack.framework,explicitFileType:wrapper.framework,includeInIndex:0,isa:PBXFileReference,name:CocoaLumberjack.framework,path:CocoaLumberjack.framework,sourceTree:BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR,,displayName:Pods_MyProject.framework,explicitFileType:wrapper.framework,includeInIndex:0,isa:PBXFileReference,name:Pods_MyProject.framework,path:Pods_MyProject.framework,sourceTree:BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR,,displayName:Pods_MyShare.framework,explicitFileType:wrapper.framework,includeInIndex:0,isa:PBXFileReference,name:Pods_MyShare.framework,path:Pods_MyShare.framework,sourceTree:BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR,,displayName:Products,isa:PBXGroup,name:Products,sourceTree:,/Products/children/displayName:CocoaLumberjack.framework,explicitFileType:wrapper.framework,includeInIndex:0,isa:PBXFileReference,name:CocoaLumberjack.framework,path:CocoaLumberjack.framework,sourceTree:BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR,/Products/CocoaLumberjack.framework

This is my `Podfile`:

```
workspace 'MyWorkspace'
xcodeproj 'MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj'

use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

link_with 'MyProject', 'MyShare'

target :MyProject do
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0.1'
end

target :MyShare do
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Core', '~> 2.0.1'
end
```

I was able to work around this problem by making both of my targets use the same `CocoaLumberjack` subspec. My working `Podfile` is below:

```
workspace 'MyWorkspace'
xcodeproj 'MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj'

use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

link_with 'MyProject', 'MyShare'

target :MyProject do
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Core', '~> 2.0.1'
end

target :MyShare do
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Core', '~> 2.0.1'
end
```

Why is this workaround necessary? What happens when I actually have different subspec dependencies between two targets?

**EDIT**

This looks related to [CocoaPods Issue 4370](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4370). I posted my example project on [github](https://github.com/hborders/CocoaPods_4370_Example).

Comment: Same issue here, upvoted! By the way, have you tried archiving the product despite the errors? Is it giving you errors related to the umbrella headers? Cocoapods + use_frameworks! + xcode 7.1 totally messed up my env :(

Comment: @ale0xB Any solution to your problem using Xcode 7.1?

Comment: Xcode 7.1 didn't help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a bug in Cocoapods -And probably it won't be fixed in a long while-

Running `export COCOAPODS_DISABLE_DETERMINISTIC_UUIDS=YES` on the Terminal seems to suppress the warnings for now.

EDIT Feb 2016:

In latest version of Cocoapods this has now been moved to the install section of the Podfile: `install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false`

Comment: They claim this was fixed in `1.0.0.beta.4` https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4370#issuecomment-188392490

Comment: No, it's not a bug of `cocoapods`. It might be caused by Xcode. I've added [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60809637/1107242)

Comment: It's probably a mistake made by Xcode when moving files from one folder to another, ref to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60809637/1107242)

Answer (score 7):

It's **caused by duplicate files in different directories**.
Sometimes **Xcode might make mistake and duplicate files** when you move files to another directory **by dragging** in Xcode's Project Navigator (press `Command + 1` to open). These duplicated files were left orphans and had not been added to the Xcode project, so everything works OK. However, `pod install` accepted all files in [Development Pods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html) including these orphans.

To find these duplicate files, I have two solutions as follows,

**Solution 1**

```sh
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f -exec basename {} + | sort | uniq -d
```

where `-path ./.git -prune -o` means to exclude `.git` directory when finding

**Solution 2**

1. Copy error messages to a text file named such as `duplicateUUIDs.txt`
2. Get sorted file names and output duplicated items

```sh
grep -E '[a-zA-Z+]+\.(h|m|swift)' -o duplicateUUIDs.txt | sort | uniq -d
```

**Next Step**

Delete unnecessary files.

Comment: Not sure, If I follow. It gives me this list: ```at.h
awaitable.h
context.h
endpoint.h
error.h
executor.h
protocol.h
reactor.h
service.h
spawn.h
stream.h```. Where do I delete them from?

Comment: @Houman Duplicated files must be located in different folders. In order to locate the  folder used by your project, open Xcode project navigator, just right click (shift + click) on the file like `at.h`, then choose `Show In Finder`, you will know the correct folder.

Answer (score 5):

Problem fixed for me by following steps: (I have also done the changes as per @ale0xB suggested)

1. Clean the project
2. Close the Xcode
3. Delete derived data
4. If you have already installed the POD, kindly delete the “.xcworkspace” & “Podfile.lock” files
5. Install pod again
6. Open “.xcworkspace” and Run

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when adding an application extension.

I fixed it by repeating the `platform :ios, '7.0'` line present in my application target to my new target as well.

Making sure the two targets use the same platform solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

write this line in podfile ==>   install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

e.g:
platform :ios, '10.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'WheeboxExamSheetScanner' do
config = use_native_modules!

Comment: Does't works, produce error when parsing podfile