# `'NBPhoneNumberDesc.h' file not found` after updating to Xcode 10.2, Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, module, cocoapods, header-files

I'm using pod [chronotruck/FlagPhoneNumber](https://github.com/chronotruck/FlagPhoneNumber/issues/103) I just updated from `High Sierra/Xcode 10.1/Swift 4.2/Cocoapoods v-1.5.3` to `Mojave 10.14.15/Xcode 10.2.1/Swift 5/Cocoapoods v-1.7.3` and I can't build because inside the `NBRegExMatcher.m` file I get the error

> 'NBPhoneNumberDesc.h' file not found

[image]

Everything worked fine before the upgrade and I never had any of these errors.

The Podfile.lock has this inside of it:

```
- FlagPhoneNumber (0.7.6):
- FlagPhoneNumber/libPhoneNumberiOS (= 0.7.6)
- FlagPhoneNumber/libPhoneNumberiOS (0.7.6)
```

The odd thing is there are several other files from that pod that also use the `#import "NBPhoneNumberDesc.h"` module but they all work fine and there aren't any errors

[image]

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33865771/4833705) but NBPhoneNumberDesc.h was already in the Public section:

[image]

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41543823/4833705) to set the SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME to match the my project's bridging header but nothing

Inside the `NBRegExMatcher.m` file (where the error is occurring) I commented out `#import NBPhoneNumberDesc.h` to see what would happen and then NBPhoneNumberUtil.h got the same error:

[image]

I notice the `libPhoneNumber-iOS` came bundled inside the `FlagPhoneNumber` pod and it's version is `libPhoneNumberiOS (0.7.6)`. I then manually [added the pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/libPhoneNumber-ios) to my project to see what would happen but it also made no difference, the error was still there. The only thing I noticed is when I added the pod manually the Podfile.lock version is `- libPhoneNumber-iOS (0.9.15)` wherein as the version that FlagPhoneNumber is using is `libPhoneNumberiOS (0.7.6)`

**Any idea how can i fix this error?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried a bunch of answers about changing things inside Build Settings > Header File and/or User Header files but none of them worked. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16783389/4833705) and it worked :)

What I had to do was change the `#import SomeFile.h` to `#import <SomeFile.h>` by using the brackets instead.

Here is the code from each file

Inside the `NBRegExMatcher.m` file I had to change these 2 modules:

```
//#import "NBPhoneNumberDesc.h" // comment this out and add the brackets below
#import <NBPhoneNumberDesc.h>
//#import "NBPhoneNumberUtil.h" // comment this out and add the brackets below
#import <NBPhoneNumberUtil.h>
```

After I changed those I also got the same error inside the `NBPhoneNumberUtil.m` and had to do the same there:

```
//#import "NBRegExMatcher.h" // comment this out and add the brackets below
#import <NBRegExMatcher.h>
```

Here are pictures of each:

`NBRegExMatcher.m` file
[image]

`NBPhoneNumberUtil.m` file
[image]

**On a side note I also had to add the `pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'` to my Podfile because a different error appeared becuase I uised the library outside of the FlagPhoneNumber pod**